# JAXB unmarshall from list to HashMap

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

There is a piece of the xml file:

```
***

<resource>
        <name>commands</name>
        <method>POST</method>
        <permissions mode="blacklist"></permissions>
        <resource>
            <name>login</name>
            <permissions mode="blacklist"></permissions>
        </resource>
        <resource>
            <name>logout</name>
            <permissions>
                <u>$all</u>
                <u>BANNED</u>
            </permissions>
        </resource>
        <resource>
            <name>register</name>
            <permissions>
                <u>GUEST</u>
            </permissions>
        </resource>
        <resource>
            <name>addbook</name>
            <permissions>
                <u>$registered</u>
            </permissions>
        </resource>
        <resource>
            <name>changepassword</name>
            <permissions>
                <u>$registered</u>
            </permissions>
        </resource>
</resource>

***
```

As you can see, the tags in it can be nested inside each other. The nested goes just one by one, as list, they don`t have parent tag .

At the moment, using JAXB, they are converted to List. But I need to have a HashMap instead of a list:

```
class Resource{
***
    private HashMap<String, Resource> resources;

    @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(ResourcesHashMapAdapter.class)
    @XmlElement(name = "resource")
    public HashMap<String, Resource> getResources() {
        return resources;
    }

    public void setResources(HashMap<String, Resource> resources) {
        this.resources = resources;
    }
***
}
```

I wrote an adapter, which with demarshallizing takes a list and returns a map, but it doesn`t work.

```
public class ResourcesHashMapAdapter extends XmlAdapter<LinkedList<Resource>, HashMap<String, Resource>> {
    @Override
    public HashMap<String, Resource> unmarshal(LinkedList<Resource> v) throws Exception {
        HashMap<String, Resource> map = new HashMap<String, Resource>();
        v.forEach(resource -> map.put(resource.getName(), resource));
        System.out.println("IN ResourcesHashMapAdapter: " + v);
        return map;
    }

    @Override
    public LinkedList<Resource> marshal(HashMap<String, Resource> v) throws Exception {
        return new LinkedList(v.values());
    }
}
```

unmarshall() is  invoked, but always gets an empty LinkedList. What should I change to perform transforming correctly?

The problem is I don`t want to wrap resource tag to resources tag

Comment: I suspect you have conflicting collection handling. Xml doesn't clearly define lists, so its up to JAXB to interpret. You'd have to debug into JAXB *before* it calls your adapter to see what data structure it has unmarshall'd 'resource' elements to and then update your adapter unmarshal() method to match the type signature. Probably something like a List<JAXBElement<Resource>>